# Sorting ng-table (null values and custom sort)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/ushoubbx/16/) js-fiddle shows an example with a null element. The wanted behavior should be:

50,51,52,53,54,null (already works)

54,53,52,51,50,null (currently is null,54,53,52,51,50)

Is it possible to use `orderBy` inside of `sortable` when the data is being sorted in decreasing order? The [documentation](http://ng-table.com/#/) also doesn't seem to elaborate on what `sortable` accepts

**EDIT:**  I've created a custom comparator for descending sort, but it doesn't seem to affect the data.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngTable'])

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, NgTableParams) {
  $scope.data = [{
    name: "Test1",
    age: 50
  }, {
    name: "Test2",
    age: 51
  }, {
    name: "Test3",
    age: 52
  }, {
    name: "Test4",
    age: 53
  }, {
    name: "Test5",
    age: 54
  }, {
    name: "Test6",
    age: null
  }];
  $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({}, {
    dataset: $scope.data
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table" show-filter="true">
    <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
      <td title="'Name'" filter="{ name: 'text'}" sortable="'name'">
        {{user.name}}</td>
      <td title="'Age'" filter="{ age: 'number'}" sortable="'age'">
        {{user.age}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't have much time right now for providing an answer but you could try [Change sort order programmatically](http://ng-table.com/#/sorting/demo-api)

Comment: actually, I think ive mostly solved it. I've updated the js fiddle. But the desc sort doesn't work correctly

https://jsfiddle.net/ushoubbx/16